# Marionette, layout within layout

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have a page that uses marionette layout to bind views to #content.

My landing page in my app is many views drawn together, so I planned to use another layout view instead of a composite view.

However currently with the code below I get:

```
TypeError: object is not a function
```

My controller.js calls views based on routes like this:

```
    app.addRegions({
      content: "#content"
    });

define([], function() {
  "use strict";
  return {
    landing: function() {
      return require(["app/views/index"], function(View) {
        return MyApp.content.show(new View());  ////LINE THROWING THE ERROR
      });
    }
  };
});
```

The sub layout causing the issue

```
define([
  "marionette",
  'app/views/images/collection',
  "tpl!app/templates/index.html"
],
  function(Marionette, ImagesView, template) {
        "use strict";
        var AppLayout, layout;
        AppLayout = void 0;
        layout = void 0;
        AppLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
          template: template(),
          regions: {
            collection1: "#images",
          }
        });
        layout = new AppLayout();
        layout.collection1.show(new ImagesView());
        return layout;
      })
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're returning a new `layout` object from your index, and then trying to use it as a function in your controller.

In your index:

```
layout = new AppLayout();
...
return layout;
```

and then in your controller:

```
return MyApp.content.show(new View());
```

You probably just need to do

```
return MyApp.content.show(View);
```

**UPDATE**
After working on this some more, we found another issue. The ordering of rendering the views was wrong. The statement `layout.collection1.show(new ImagesView());` won't actually render anything because `layout` itself hasn't been rendered yet. The solution to this was to move that statement into the `onRender` method of the `AppLayout`. This way, when `MyApp.content.show(View)` is called, it will automatically render the `ImagesView` at the correct time.

Comment: That gives me a "cannot call render on undefined" inside marionette line 849 which is the show function

Comment: Which show function is it erroring on? The `layout.collection1.show(...)` or the `MyApp.content.show(View)`?

Comment: Also, I don't think the order you are rendering the items will work. You're calling `layout.collection1.show(...)` before you call `layout.render()` (which is done by `MyApp.content.show(View)`). The `collection1` region object exists, but the element in the DOM that it's trying to attach to doesn't. It won't exist until the layout is rendered. See http://jsfiddle.net/craigjennings11/GLgZ6/ for an example of this.

Comment: So I'm using the following without error, but the image view render definetly isnt called, or if it is: its not updating the #images div the regions bound to:     layout = new AppLayout();
    layout.render();
    layout.collection1.show(new ImagesView());
    return layout;

Comment: Just a couple of debugging suggestions. Make sure you're returning a View from the `ImageView` module, not an instance of the view (although I think you would be getting errors if you were doing that). Also, make sure you aren't re-rendering the `layout` view in your controller (through calling `show`). Calling `show` on your `layout` after you've rendered it would first close the region and then re-render it, thus removing any ImagesView rendering that was done.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37350/discussion-between-craig-j-and-azz0r)